# How can I not specify any return type and yet print my arrays in a tabular form?

Tags: java, arrays, function, methods, subroutine

The goal of this program is to declare three separate arrays and then write a function to display them in a tabular form. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiDArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many rows?");
        int length = input.nextInt();

        int [] ID = new int[length];
        for(int counter = 0; counter<length; counter++) {
            System.out.println("Enter ID number "+(counter+1));
            ID[counter] = input.nextInt();
        }

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many names?");
        int words = scan.nextInt();

        String [] Name = new String[words];
        for(int counter = 0; counter<words; counter++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Name "+(counter+1));
            Name[counter] = scan.next();
        }

        Scanner figure = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many Salaries?");
        int sal = figure.nextInt();

        int []Salary = new int[sal];
        for(int counter = 0; counter<sal; counter++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Salary "+(counter+1));
            Salary[counter] = figure.nextInt();
        }

        input.close();
        scan.close();
        figure.close();

        System.out.println("ID"+" "+"Name"+" "+"Salary");
        System.out.println("Content of Array: " + (display(ID, Name, Salary)));
}

public static String display(int x[], String y[], int z[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i<x.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(x[i]+"   "+y[i]+"   "+z[i]);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Which prints out my system input in this way:

```
ID Name Salary
1   JK   3000
2   MK   4000
3   CK   5000
null
```

However, what I would like to see instead is the same without the "null" part.

```
ID Name Salary
1   JK   3000
2   MK   4000
3   CK   5000
```

If I do not specify any return type, I get errors.

Comment: Change `String display` to `void display` and remove `return null`

Comment: And instead of `System.out.println("Content of Array: " + (display(ID, Name, Salary))`, just call `display(ID, Name, Salary)` (you are doing the printing in the `display` method, so you don't need to return a value from it to print)

Comment: @Sedrick If I do as you suggested, I get an error message, "The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void" at the line  'System.out.println("Content of Array: " + (display(ID, Name, Salary)));'

Comment: @mapeters Yes, that did the trick. Thanks guys!

Comment: Also, this code is dangerous. You should not reprompt "How many ___?" for each type of thing. You should only ask how many rows once, and then reuse that number for all the columns. (try entering 5 for number of rows, and then 2 for number of names, and you should get an exception)

Comment: @mapeters Working on that... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning null and then concatenating it in your calling println statement

```
 System.out.println("Content of Array: " + (display(ID, Name, Salary)));
```

You could do something like

```
System.out.print("Content of Array: ");
String ret = display(ID, Name, Salary);
```

If you are trying to write a method without a return type, use void.  You shouldn't be concatenating a void return to a string though.

```
public static void display(int x[], String y[], int z[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i<x.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(x[i]+"   "+y[i]+"   "+z[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdul Ahad